# When so many people have asked for boon why didnt they asked to eliminate crime and injustice from the world?

Tags: shiva, krishna, yogi, boon, tapasya

When so many people have asked for boon why didnt they asked to eliminate crime and injustice from the world?Why dont they ask for it now?

Comment: because crime is relative. a thief could ask for boon to "eliminate police" and police could ask for boon to "eliminate thieves". whom should Bhagavan eliminate ? Neither. It's a game. whoever is stronger wins. whoever is more righteous becomes stronger.

Comment: How could a thief be righteous in general. Shouldnt god help the good?

Comment: it was only an analogy. better example would be two teams india and australia playing cricket and bhagavan is referee. if anyone commits fouls, he punishes them, otherwise the stronger team wins.

Comment: Shouldnt god help the good?Doesnt god want the good to win?

Comment: he does help the good. now, imagine somebody stole in the past. how would you punish him ? 2 ways - either king punishes him by cutting off his hand, OR, some other thief steals money from this person. the 2nd method is what you see in the world. there will always be "injustice" because it is actually justice.